# How to convert LinearPCM to a compressed format using MonoTouch AudioConverter?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, audio-converter

I am recording LinearPCM using MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.InputAudioQueue and need to convert it prior to uploading to a web service. I want to keep recoding as LinearPCM so that I can handle interruptions (phone calls), playback audio (play, rewind, fast forward etc.).

Apple does support audio conversions using their [Audio Conversion Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioConverterServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) and see that MonoTouch includes functionality at MonoTouch.AudioUnitWrapper._AudioConverter. However, I can't find a single MonoTouch example or StackOverflow question about it. :(

Does anyone know how to get audio converted using MonoTouch? I have looked into 3rd party libraries such as [NSpeex](http://nspeex.codeplex.com), but want to keep it as native as possible.

Any help or pointers would be awesome! Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my question by converting to .m4a using using the MonoTouch sample AudioQueueOfflineRenderDemo.

[AudioQueueOfflineRenderDemo @ GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/AudioQueueOfflineRenderDemo)